# How can I display the sound information? Like equalizers do

Tags: ios, swift

I have this function. I use it to recognize the speech of the user.

```
func recordAndRecognizeSpeech()
{
    let node = audioEngine.inputNode
    let recordingFormat = node.outputFormat(forBus: 0)
    node.installTap(onBus: 0, bufferSize: 1024, format: recordingFormat) { (buffer, _) in
        self.request.append(buffer)
    }
    audioEngine.prepare()
    do
    {
        try audioEngine.start()
        didStartRecording?()
        didStartStopRecordTimer = false
    } catch{
        return print(error)
    }
    guard let myRecognizer = SFSpeechRecognizer() else {
        print("a recognizer is not supported for this locale")
        return
    }
    if myRecognizer.isAvailable == false
    {
        print("a recognizer is not available right now")
        return
    }
    recognitionTask = speechRecognizer?.recognitionTask(with: request, resultHandler: { (result, error) in
        if let result = result{
            var bestString = result.bestTranscription.formattedString
            print(bestString)
            bestString = self.cutString(str: bestString)!
            self.didSpeak?(bestString)
            self.startTimer()
        } else if let error = error{
            print(error)
        }
    })
}
```

I would like to display some sound bars like this:[example](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=equalizer&atb=v144-3&iar=images&iax=images&ia=images&iai=http%3A%2F%2Ffc09.deviantart.net%2Ffs70%2Ff%2F2010%2F102%2F0%2F8%2FEqualizer_by_speedster2000.jpg). There is very little information on the internet and any help would be appreciated.

Comment: That is a mathematically very complex thing to do. You need to read up about FFT (fast fourier transformation). Not sure there are some open-source implementations of it.

Comment: at least how do I get the information about the sound volume for specific frequencies?